# Usage of 'want'

Tags: word-usage, sentence-construction

I have seen the following both sentences are used. What is the difference between them, if there is any?

> I want my books read.
>
> I want my books to be read.

Comment: There is absolutely no difference. They mean the same thing.

Comment: Please use another title; your question is not about the use of want.